# Does HLSL implement Shader Model LOD instruction?

Tags: directx, hlsl, level-of-detail, assembly

The DX Shader Model 5.0 [has a `lod` instruction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh447175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It returns "the LOD (level of detail) that would be used for texture filtering".

Does HLSL have a built-in intrinsic that can do the same? I know I could [evaluate the LOD *manually*](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/28430/39043), but I'm wondering if there's a better way.

Comment: What? You refer to a hlsl instruction and then ask if the same one is available? could you clear up your question abit?

Comment: @Tordin They seem to be referring to an existing *DX Shader Model* instruction and want to know if *GLSL* has a similar one. I've edited to clarify.

Comment: @Anko No, there is Shader Model Assembly and HLSL. The first one is like x86 assembly and HLSL is like C language. So we generally write shaders in HLSL and it is compiled to asm code by DirectX (which can be viewed using Shader Dump feature).

Comment: Finally found it! It's Object.CalculateLevelOfDetail not listed under Shader Model 5 Reference, but under 4.

Comment: @michalo2882 Yeah, the organization of the MSDN docs is kind of annoying - SM5 includes everything in SM4, so the SM5 docs only have the stuff that was *new* in SM5.  Anyway, you should post an answer to your question and accept it.

Comment: @Nathan Reed Of course, I just had to wait 8 hours before I could post the answer (as I'm a new member) and now I have to wait another 16 hours to accept it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found it! It's [Object.CalculateLevelOfDetail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff471359%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It's not listed under Shader Model 5 Reference, but under 4.